# USB C Hub + MacOs High Sierra with two monitors stuck on mirroring

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, macos-highsierra

I am currently using an Apple MacBook - just one usb C port - with a hub that allows me to use an HDMI and a VGA port.

I have tried everything - SMC reset, PRAM reset, holding the option key to detect monitors - but nothing change the current state.

At the moment what I have is the MacBook screen and one of the external monitor as extended and the other one as mirror of the second. I would like to have both of them as extended desktop. If I use the system profiler, just one of the screen is recognised. I tried the same via terminal with  system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType but again just one monitor is recognised.

Any suggestions?